# C# Networking TCP/IP?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, networking, tcp

I am in need of some websites where I can buy C# WinForms networking libraries/components/dll's from. Can anybody please suggest any? They should be pretty cheap, but any and all links are welcome :)

I can only find one website, and I don't like the look of what they have.

Thank you

Comment: .NET includes the basics of UDP, TCP, HTTP and FTP (client) itself. So what functionality are you looking for in a library?

Comment: I just cannot get anything to work, I am HOPELESS at networking stuff and everything I've downloaded (tutorials, sample apps etc) never work. The errors range. I just think it'd be in my own best interests to buy something, unless I can magically write something myself that works within 4days...

Comment: Have a look into WCF, the introductory videos will get you up and running in an hour.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with networking?

Comment: What are you trying to communicate between the computers?  Most likely you will need to write a significant amount of code to handle your specific cases.  The code I linked below is a great starting point for the base class implementations.

Answer (score 3):

[Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx)

I would suggest looking at [these introductory videos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/first-steps-with-wcf.aspx) on MSDN website, as they're more then you need to get you up and runnign quickly. Anything more advanced, there's plenty of resources/books available.

Price: £0.00 - Free

Comment: Could you explain in what scenario to use WCF ? I have a vague understanding of what it does. WCF looks very bulky though

Comment: +1 Using WCF for TCP/IP is by far the easiest way to go.  One short example of how to do this:  http://weblogs.asp.net/ralfw/archive/2007/04/14/a-truely-simple-example-to-get-started-with-wcf.aspx

Comment: Yes WCF isn't the lightest and fastest, but for most scenarios it is more then enough. What are you trying to communicate across the network? Is latency a big issue? E.g. Obviously you wouldn't use WCF in some sort of real time game, but if its a data application WCF should in most cases be more the appropriate.

Comment: @Chris nice post, i wish i had that when i had to put together a quick TCP app :P i took the long route of figuring out all the config files/end points etc...

Answer (score 0):

There are socket code examples from MS located here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w89fhyex(v=VS.71).aspx

Comment: Those are .NET 1.1 examples probably a bit outdated. Here are a few more socketed TCP examples : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dottys/socketprogdtrp11222005023030am/socketprogdtrp.aspx (used this myself) & http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-simple-threaded-tcp-server